# Converting matrix into a list using Shell script

Tags: linux, list, shell, matrix

I wanted to convert a matrix into a list using a shell script. Could anyone suggest me a way to do it using shell?

This is how a matrix looks like

```
     hello  a|b
     hi     b|c
```

Now I want a matrix like bellow:

```
hello   a
hello   b
hi  b
hi  c
```

Is there any way to do it using shell?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could be a line like `hello a b c d|e` ? what would be the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command:

```
awk -F'[| ]+' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1 "\t" $i}' file
```

will convert:

```
hello a|b|c
hi    b|c|d
```

into:

```
hello   a
hello   b
hello   c
hi      b
hi      c
hi      d
```

Comment: there is a tab between hello"\t"a|b|c, this doesnt work with tab